# Gmail Promotions tab - Is registration required?

Tags: gmail-promo-tab

In Email markup guide, it is mentioned that we need to [register with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) in order to send the markups with Gmail. Does this requirement apply to sending emails annotated for Gmail Promotions tab?

Answer (score 0):

No, the page you are referring to is for the other email markups that only show in the Updates Tab. 
For the Gmail Promo Tab enriched preview and annotated logo in the Primary tab teaser when your email is bundled created with the annotation, there is no registration required. 
The script tag can be added to the head of your email template(s), you can customize the 5 features for the campaign (can be populated with merges or dynamically - should be similar to your current creation process), and then you are all set. All the information for the enriched preview is information already in your email. Mix and match the features to create the best enriched preview to drive your goals (if not using a feature, leave blank).